# Setting authorization header in https library in NodeJS (For Cloud Function request)

Tags: node.js, https, google-cloud-functions

How do you correctly set authorization header in a Https library in NodeJS.
I am doing the following:

```
const https = require('https');
...
const optionsCFS = {
                  hostname: process.env.CLOUD_URL,
                  port: 443,
                  timeout: 5000,
                  path: process.env.CLOUD_ORDER_SAVE_PATH,
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Length': (new TextEncoder().encode(CFSdata)).length,//CFSdata.length,
                    'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`, // ? 
                  }
                }
```

I am getting a 401 error from the Cloud Function side.
It works with node-fetch library and I use the following format for it:

```
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `bearer ${token}`},
      });
```

Comment: If you have a different question after getting an answer, please ask it separately. Don't edit questions into a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get `401` if you're using an incorrect ID token. First, make sure that your user (or service) account has **Cloud Functions Invoker** role on IAM.

Then, [generate your ID token](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers) by running this command:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

I'm using this sample code to call my Cloud Function which accepts POST requests and it works just fine:

```
var https = require('https');

function postCode() {
  var payload = '{"name":"donnald"}';
  const token = 'eyJhbxxxxx';

  var post_options = {
      host: '[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net',
      path: '/func-post',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(payload),
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
  };

  var post_req = https.request(post_options, res => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', chunk => {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
      });
  });

  post_req.write(payload);
  post_req.end();
}

postCode()
```

Comment: Where is your calling function hosted and how will you do it in production? My calling bit is hosted on the AppEngine and I have updated the code above.

Comment: @DJS my calling function is hosted on a Compute Engine instance. Either way it looks like your question was updated and I find it completely different to the original one. I posted another answer on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428509/how-to-correctly-get-token-for-cloud-functions-in-nodejs-running-on-appengine/

Comment: @DJS After reviewing it, please let me know if my answer helped you. I will try to update if I missed anything