# How to CORRECTLY get token for Cloud Functions in NodeJS running on AppEngine?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am having problems getting the correct token for triggering my cloud function.

When testing through POSTMAN I get the token by running the following command:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

and my functions works correctly.

But on my server I am using the following code. I also do see the token but I get 401 with this token.

```
// Constants------------
const metadataServerTokenURL = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';

async function gToken(){
  let token='';
  try{
      // Fetch the token
      const tokenResponse = await fetch(metadataServerTokenURL + 'https://'+process.env.CLOUD_URL, { //URL WITHOUT THE PATH
        headers: {
          'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google',
        },
      });
     token = await tokenResponse.text();
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  return token;
}
```

**---------EDIT-------**

The calling function::

```
app.get("/",  async function(req , res){
  try {
    const token = await getToken();
    console.log(`Token: ${token}`);
    const functionResponse = await fetch('https://'+process.env.CLOUD_URL+process.env.PATH_TO_FUNC, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
      });
    console.log(`Status: ${await functionResponse.status}`);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send('Something went wrong')
  }
})
```

My server is my NodeJS code running on AppEngine.
What am I doing wrong please?

**----------EDIT 2--------------**
I entered the two tokens received using two different ways, they show different information for some reason.  Please see below::
Token from the server
[image]

Token using gcloud command locally (which works)::[image]

Server code and cloud functions are both hosted in the same region, and are a part of the same project.

`process.env.CLOUD_URL > "e****-***2-c******-e******2.cloudfunctions.net"`

Comment: HTTP Error 401 often means that you are not authorizing (or correctly authorizing) the HTTP request. Show your code that makes the request using the Identity Token. Your code that fetches the token looks OK. For problems like this you should create a complete example that reproduces the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. Details added.

Comment: 1) Your HTTP request looks OK. 2) You are making a POST request without a request body. 3) Validate that the Identity Token contains the correct audience. Use this Google endpoint to validate and see the Identity Token: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=ID_TOKEN 4) Verify that the calling system has the correct date/time and time zone.

Comment: Can you share the full content of the audience that your provide? `https://'+process.env.CLOUD_URL` -> hide only your project ID at the beginning.

Comment: 1) You are masking too much information. The only items that are private would be the email address and project ID / Project Number. 2) Your `aud` (audience) is missing the Cloud Function "Function Name" in the URL.

Comment: This is just a guess, but it doesn't look like the audience you specify is including the function path. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#functions-bearer-token-example-nodejs shows code that includes this path. I also recommend you log the header values you create for manual debugging. You can try to make the same request from curl before the bearer token expires to examine the behavior more closely.

Comment: Thank you. I added the PATH as well and now it works. It is people like you who make other people achieve greater things. Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What @Charles and @John mentioned in the comment is correct. You should include the name of the receiving function in the audience:

As mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function):

> In the calling function, you'll need to create a Google-signed OAuth ID token **with the audience (aud) set to the URL of the receiving function**.

```
const metadataServerTokenURL = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';
...

// Fetch the token
const tokenResponse = await fetch(metadataServerTokenURL + `https://${process.env.CLOUD_URL}/${FUNCTION_NAME}`, {
  headers: {
    'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google',
  }
```

The audience should look like your HTTP trigger URL. If you decode your JWT ID token, `aud` looks like this:

```
{
  "aud": "https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/func-post",
  "azp": "117513711437850867551",
  "exp": 1614653346,
  "iat": 1614649746,
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "117513711437850867551"
}
```